# Select all the titles from BaseX with xpath

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath, xquery, basex

How do I [query](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14966363/262852) the book titles with the `BaseX` GUI using `xpath`?

[image: database]

[Sample](https://www.w3schools.com/xml/xpath_examples.asp) `XML` which loaded into the database:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<bookstore>

<book category="cooking">
  <title lang="en">Everyday Italian</title>
  <author>Giada De Laurentiis</author>
  <year>2005</year>
  <price>30.00</price>
</book>

<book category="children">
  <title lang="en">Harry Potter</title>
  <author>J K. Rowling</author>
  <year>2005</year>
  <price>29.99</price>
</book>

<book category="web">
  <title lang="en">XQuery Kick Start</title>
  <author>James McGovern</author>
  <author>Per Bothner</author>
  <author>Kurt Cagle</author>
  <author>James Linn</author>
  <author>Vaidyanathan Nagarajan</author>
  <year>2003</year>
  <price>49.99</price>
</book>

<book category="web">
  <title lang="en">Learning XML</title>
  <author>Erik T. Ray</author>
  <year>2003</year>
  <price>39.95</price>
</book>

</bookstore>
```

directions:

> Select all the titles
>
> The following example selects all the title nodes: Example

```
/bookstore/book/title
```

Where and how do I run that query from within `BaseX`?

Comment: What do you mean by `xbase`?

Comment: pardon, basex I mean.

Comment: `xpath` is a subset of `xquery`, yes?  I imagine `xpath` will work anywhere you can use an `xquery`.  I've used `xpath`s from the [`XQuery` Input Bar](http://docs.basex.org/wiki/Graphical_User_Interface#Input_Bar) and also from the editor.  I believe you can also select an xpath from the Explorer and view a selection's `xpath` in the MAP.

Comment: After clicking a selection so that the result populates with desired output how do I replicate that with an `xpath` query from the input bar?  Rather than run a query first, I want to find the result, then generate the query for that result.

Comment: Hmmm, I'm not aware of a way to select a specific element after clicking in a BaseX visualization.  You can "Copy Path" from a visualization but I think it's path is for all elements at that level, etc.  I.e., this should work fine for selecting all titles in your example, but I don't think BaseX will calculate a xpath for a specific title.

Comment: I was thinking of the `console` in a browser, how that will calculate an `xpath` for a title.  The visualization from BaseX is quite helpful.